# PUT, PATCH, DELETE request does not send data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http

I am using a php route class to handle http request such as get, post, delete, etc. GET and POST dont have any issue(as expected) however when using Jquery Ajax to send PUT, PATCH, DELETE request the data is not sent to the server

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/demo',
  method: "PATCH", //DELETE or PUT
  data: {name: "Ryan", age: 40},
  success: function (data, status) {
    $('#cont').html(data);
  }
});
```

on the server side

```
print_r($_REQUEST)
```

Always prints an empty array meaning, the data specified in the request was not sent. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There are more concrete ways of testing whether or not data is being sent. (the browser's network tab)

Comment: $_REQUEST: [_" An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE."_](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php). PHP doesn't parse data into that super global for PUT / DELETE requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_REQUEST` does not contain the HTTP request you are sending. If you want to get access to the body, you can read it via `php://input`. Easiest way to get the entire body is:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
```